# Unity. Не работает свайп

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр, ui, mobile

опытные юнитисты. Меню должно выезжать по свайпу вниз и уезжать обратно по свайпу вверх. Можете глянуть бегло код и подсказать почему свайп не работает на iPhone? Написал напарник-джун, немного отрефакторил код, но он не тестил на мобильниках, а оказывается на iPhone это не работает :) Закомментированный код - это моя попытка избавиться от проверки на мобильник и посмотреть результат, но ничего не поменялось - на свайп меню не реагирует. Возможно у кого-то будет желание и хватит опыта тыкнуть в ошибки.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Menu : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private float _speed = 2000f;
    [SerializeField]
    private float _slideDistance = 480f;

    private Vector2 _startPosition;
    private Vector2 _endPosition;

    /// <summary>
    /// Подключаем триггер на свайп
    /// Задаем стартовую позицию меню
    /// </summary>
    void Start()
    {
        Vector2 defaultPosition = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y);

        SwipeDetection.SwipeEvent += OnSwipe;

        _startPosition = defaultPosition;
        _endPosition = defaultPosition;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        float step = _speed * Time.deltaTime;

        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(
            new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y),
            _endPosition,
            step
        );
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Устанавливает конечную позицию для меню
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="direction">Vector2</param>
    private void OnSwipe(Vector2 direction)
    {
        _endPosition.y = direction.y == -1
            ? _startPosition.y + direction.y * _slideDistance
            : _startPosition.y;
    }
}
```

SwipeDetection (вся логика по свайпу в основном тут)

```
using UnityEngine;

public class SwipeDetection : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static event OnSwipeInput SwipeEvent;
    public delegate void OnSwipeInput(Vector2 direction);

    [SerializeField]
    private float _deadZone = 80f;

    private bool _isMobile;
    private bool _isSwiping;
    private Vector2 _tapPosition;
    private Vector2 _swipeDelta;

    void Start()
    {
        _swipeDelta = Vector2.zero;
        _isMobile = Application.isMobilePlatform;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) || Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            _isSwiping = true;
            //_tapPosition = _isMobile
            //    ? Input.GetTouch(0).position
            //    : (Vector2) Input.mousePosition;
            _tapPosition = (Vector2)Input.mousePosition;
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0) || CheckTouchOnMobile())
        {
            ResetSwipe();
        }

        IdentifySwipeDelta();
        SwipeEventStart();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Определяем направление
    /// </summary>
    private void IdentifySwipeDelta()
    {
        if (_isSwiping)
        {
            if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) || Input.touchCount > 0)
            {
                //_swipeDelta = _isMobile
                //    ? Input.GetTouch(0).position - _tapPosition
                //    : (Vector2)Input.mousePosition - _tapPosition;
                _swipeDelta = (Vector2)Input.mousePosition - _tapPosition;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Стартуем событие "свайпа"
    /// </summary>
    private void SwipeEventStart()
    {
        if (SwipeEvent != null && _swipeDelta.magnitude > _deadZone)
        {
            Vector2 swipeDirection = _swipeDelta.y > 0 ? Vector2.up : Vector2.down;

            if (Mathf.Abs(_swipeDelta.x) < Mathf.Abs(_swipeDelta.y))
            {
                SwipeEvent(swipeDirection);
            }

            ResetSwipe();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Проверяем есть ли нажатие на мобильном устройстве
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>bool</returns>
    private bool CheckTouchOnMobile()
    {
        if (!_isMobile) return false;

        TouchPhase phase = Input.GetTouch(0).phase;

        return phase == TouchPhase.Canceled || phase == TouchPhase.Ended;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Обнуляем все значения
    /// </summary>
    private void ResetSwipe()
    {
        Vector2 zeroPosition = Vector2.zero;

        _isSwiping = false;

        _tapPosition = zeroPosition;
        _swipeDelta = zeroPosition;
    }
}
```

Comment: Сообщения от `Debug.Log()` отображаются в консоли `XCode` при запуске с провода. Думаю за пару итераций сможете сами найти.

Comment: я здесь выкладывал готовый свайп, авось он тебе подойдет https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/937884/Как-отловить-ивент-свайпа-swipe-в-unity

Comment: Спасибо. Гляну на днях)