# Замена кнопок на свайп Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity3d

есть такой вот кусок кода:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow)) {
        this.movement.SetDirection(Vector2.up);
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow)) {
        this.movement.SetDirection(Vector2.down);
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow)) {
        this.movement.SetDirection(Vector2.left);
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow)) {
        this.movement.SetDirection(Vector2.right);
    }
```

Вопрос, как заменить эти кнопки на свайпы

Answer (score 1):

Готово:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Pacman : MonoBehaviour
{    
    private bool tap;
    private bool isDraging = false;
    private Vector2 startTouch, swipeDelta;

    private void Update()
    {

        tap = false;

        #region Standalone Inputs
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            tap = true;
            isDraging = true;
            startTouch = Input.mousePosition;
        }
        else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)) {
            isDraging = false;
            Reset();
        }
        #endregion

        #region Mobile Inputs
        if (Input.touches.Length > 0) {
            if (Input.touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Began) {
                tap = true;
                isDraging = true;
                startTouch = Input.touches[0].position;
            } else if (Input.touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Ended || Input.touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Canceled){
                isDraging = false;
                Reset();
            }
        }
        #endregion

        swipeDelta = Vector2.zero;
        if (isDraging) {
            if (Input.touches.Length > 0)
                swipeDelta = Input.touches[0].position - startTouch;
            else if (Input.GetMouseButton(0)) 
                swipeDelta = (Vector2)Input.mousePosition - startTouch;
            
        }

        if (swipeDelta.magnitude > 125) {
            float x = swipeDelta.x;
            float y = swipeDelta.y;
            if (Mathf.Abs(x) > Mathf.Abs(y))
            {
                if (x < 0)
                    this.movement.SetDirection(Vector2.left);
                else 
                    this.movement.SetDirection(Vector2.right);
            }
            else {
                if (y < 0)
                    this.movement.SetDirection(Vector2.down);
                else
                    this.movement.SetDirection(Vector2.up);
            }

            Reset();
        }     
    }

    private void Reset()
    {
        startTouch = swipeDelta = Vector2.zero;
        isDraging = false;
    }

    public Vector2 SwipeDelta { get { return swipeDelta; } }
    public bool swipeLeft { get { return swipeLeft; } }
    public bool swipeRight { get { return swipeRight; } }
    public bool swipeUp { get { return swipeUp; } }
    public bool swipeDown { get { return swipeDown; } }
}
```

это скрипт для свайпа, пользуйтесь на здоровье :)

Answer (score 1):

можно пользоваться поиском на сайте - он часто помогает.

код свайп детектора взял отсюда: [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/937884/Как-отловить-ивент-свайпа-swipe-в-unity/937885#937885](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/937884/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BF%D0%B0-swipe-%D0%B2-unity/937885#937885)

могут быть некоторые мелкие синтаксические ошибки т.к. нету возможности проверить код полноценно.

```
SwipeDetector swipeDetector = new SwipeDetector();

void start() 
{
   swipeDetector.OnSwipe += SwipeLeftReaction;
   swipeDetector.OnSwipe += SwipeRightReaction;
}

public void SwipeLeftReaction(SwipeData data)
{
    if (data.direction == .Left)
       Debug.Log("swipe Left");
}

public void SwipeRightReaction(SwipeData data)
{
    if (data.direction == .Right)
       Debug.Log("swipe Right");
}
```