# Как сделать так чтобы объект реагировал только на вертикальный свайп

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть код который двигает объект по оси z,но при этом не учитывается какой был свайп горизонтальный или вертикальный. Как сделать так чтобы объект реагировал только на вертикальный свайп?

```
public class Swipe : MonoBehaviour
{ 
                                                                                 
          public Rigidbody rb;

          private Vector3 position;

          private readonly float _speed = 0.05f;

          private Vector2 _startPos;


   void FixUpdate()
    {
     if (Input.touchCount > 0)
     {
        var touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        switch (touch.phase)
        {
            case TouchPhase.Began:
                _startPos = touch.position;
                break;

            case TouchPhase.Moved:
                var dir = touch.position - _startPos;
                var pos = transform.position + new Vector3(transform.position.x, 
          transform.position.y, dir.y);
                transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, pos, 
          Time.deltaTime * _speed);
                var direction = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position);
                break;

         }
       
     } 
    }
 }
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как отловить ивент свайпа / Swipe в Unity?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/937884/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bf%d0%b0-swipe-%d0%b2-unity)